# Deploy Aplicacion Web MVC no genera Controlllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

tengo una duda, respecto de una `app web` con patrón arquitectónico (MVC) con `VS2017 Comunity Edition`, y `sql server`.
Resulta que la app compila sin problemas, esta hecha en varias capas, y al momento de publicar la solución, genera el directorio *BIN*, *CONTENT*, *SCIPTS* y *VIEWS*, pero curiosamente no genera el directorio *CONTROLLERS* (de hecho hay un controller de inicio)
Esta app la estoy publicando a trabes del sistema de archivos, y luego la copio a un sitio web con **IIS** en un **windows 2008**.

La app funciona de manera correcta, pero aquí me surge la duda, porque en otra app web (en otro server) aunque bajo las mismas condiciones, si me genera una carpeta controller?? (la 2da app tiene muchos mas controladores que la primera)

¿Sera que los controllers de la primera app, quedan "embebidos" dentro de las dlls?, de ser así, ¿Como podría evitar esto ya que la persona que tenga que retocar los controllers y las vistas, podría tener problemas si pretende actualizar el proyecto?

saludos y gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Está bien que no se genere la carpeta Controllers. Todo el código C# o *codebehind* va embebido en las DLLs que se generan por cada proyecto que tienes en tu solución. Esas DLLs las puedes ver en la carpeta `bin`. Aunque también depende de las opciones de publicación, si pusiste la opción `Precompile during publishing` donde se permite publicar un sitio precompilado y el IIS se encargará de realizar una compilación internamente cuando sea accedido al sitio precompilado ;)

Comment: @Flxtr no sería bueno que tu comentario lo transformes a respuesta :)